# Move some server code from my view to an HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the statement below in my view:

```
window.location = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("SearchAffaires","Search", (SearchCriteriaAffaire)Session["SearchCriteriaAffaire"]))'
```

How can I transform this by using an helper? Something like:

In my view:

```
window.location = '@Html.NavigateSearchPage()'
```

In HtmlHelpers.cs:

```
    public static string NavigateSearchPage(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        // what do I have to code here?
    }
```

Or maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UrlHelper extension would make more sense in this scenario than an HTML helper.

You could do that as follows:

```
    public static string SearchPage(this UrlHelper helper)
    {
        return helper.Action("SearchAffaires",
               "Search", 
               (SearchCriteriaAffaire)Session["SearchCriteriaAffaire"]);
    }
```

View:

```
window.location = '@Html.Raw(Url.SearchPage())';
```

Comment: Missing ; from the helper.Action above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the generated link, make your helper return an [`HtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.aspx), use the `UrlHelper` instead of `HtmlHelper` ans simply call the same method you are using in the view:

```
public static HtmlString NavigateSearchPage(this UrlHelper helper)
{
    return helper.Action("SearchAffaires","Search", 
        (SearchCriteriaAffaire)Session["SearchCriteriaAffaire"]);
}
```

Comment: One too many closing brackets on the helper.Action function above.

Comment: @Chris - Fixed, Thanks. I had just copy/pasted it from OP's question :)

Comment: No prob. Thought so. Original had an Url.Raw function around it which is where the extra came from.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the way you have to go.

```
public static string NavigateSearchPage(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext)
    return helper.Raw(urlHelper.Action("SearchAffaires","Search", (SearchCriteriaAffaire)helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Session["SearchCriteriaAffaire"])));
}
```